# handle mouse move and click together in javafx

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, mouseevent

I'm trying to build a javafx app in which i need to respond to mouse movements and clicks together just like what happens in counter strike when you shoot. But the problem is when i press the mouse button it will not respond to mouse movements anymore until i release the mouse button. I want them both to work together in parallel. I tried to set my listeners in separate threads but it doesn't work.This is an image of a gun pointer.

```
Image image = new Image("/pointer.png");  // a 25*25 PNG icon
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
scene.setCursor(Cursor.NONE);
```

and then :

```
scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
        imageView.setX(e.getX());
        imageView.setY(e.getY());
    });

scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep());
```

I also tried to put them in separate threads, it doesn't work either but if it does there is another problem, i cannot change the coordinates of a javafx component in another thread and i get this error -even if it doesn't cause an error it will not work:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread

scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                imageView.setX(e.getX());  // here i cannot do stuff related
                imageView.setY(e.getY());  // to javafx components
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    });

    scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep());
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    });
```

I also tried this but it doesn't work either

```
scene.setOnMouseMoved(e -> {
        imageView.setX(e.getX());
        imageView.setY(e.getY());

        scene.setOnMousePressed(event -> Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep());
    });
```

So how i can handle this problem, how i can respond to mouse clicks in parallel with mouse movements with no conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the mouse is clicked and held, instead of `onMouseMoved` use `onMouseDragged` with same method signature. I believe that should satisfy your requirements.

As for the exception, just for your information, in order to run code on JavaFX Application Thread simply call `Platform.runLater(some Runnable code);` So in your case

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                imageView.setX(e.getX()); // this will now run fine
                imageView.setY(e.getY());
            });
        }
    };
```

Nevertheless, there is absolutely no need for extra threads, since the capture of events will be propagated only to the JavaFX Application Thread. There are various ways of filtering or handling those events. More information about events can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm)